# Обратиться к элементу датафрейма

Tags: python, pandas, анализ

Применила следующий код:

```
    df_all = pd.concat([df1, df2],axis='columns', keys=['First', 'Second'], sort=False)
    df_final = df_all.swaplevel(axis='columns')[df1.columns[1:]]
```

Тепперь надо получить все элементы First, где ячейки NaN. Как вызвать эти элементы? [image: результат кода]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что вы нашли метод cross-section - это хорошо. но он не решает поставленной вами задачи. Нужно не только выделить нужные столбцы в мультииндексе, но еще и найти строки, содержащие NaN.

При df:

```
A first half        second half       
B      first second       first second
0        1.0    1.0         1.0    1.0
1        2.0    2.0         NaN    2.0
2        3.0    3.0         3.0    3.0
3        4.0    4.0         4.0    4.0
4        NaN    NaN         5.0    5.0
```

Можно сделать так:

```
df.xs("first", level=-1, axis=1).loc[df.isna().any(axis=1)]
```

```
A  first half  second half
1         2.0          NaN
4         NaN          5.0
```

**UPDATE**

Для того, чтобы получить строку, где все элементы first равны np.nan,
можно сделать так:
df:

```
A first half        second half       
B      first second       first second
0        1.0    1.0         1.0    1.0
1        2.0    2.0         NaN    2.0
2        3.0    3.0         3.0    3.0
3        4.0    4.0         4.0    4.0
4        NaN    NaN         NaN    5.0
```

```
df[df.xs("first", level=-1, axis=1).isna().all(axis=1)]
```

```
A first half        second half       
B      first second       first second
4        NaN    NaN         NaN    5.0
```

Comment: мне скорее нужно получить строку где все элементы 'first' равны NaN. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: я обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: интересно участие в полугодовалом проекте в роли Data Scientist ( прогнозирование популярности постов в соцсетях)? telegram aljona_Barbanova

Answer (score 0):

Нашла, что обратиться можно вот так:
res.xs('First', axis='columns', level=-1)

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Кок-то странное решение у вас. Оно как отражает стремление найди строки с NaN?